# topological sort subset of nodes in graph

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm, topological-sort

I have a large graph which represents a set of dependencies.  A user can specify that they want to use a certain number of these dependencies and I need to figure out the correct order to use them (they may specify dependent nodes which are not directly related, but which are dependent through other nodes in the graph).

Currently I am implementing this by running a topological sort of the graph and stopping once all of the nodes the user specified have been sorted.  However, this does not result in a minimal sort of the needed dependencies and I have to go back and try to remove any unneeded nodes.

Is there some better way to do this or known algorithm for finding the topological sort of a subset of nodes?

Comment: "does not result in a minimal sort of the needed dependencies" - what does that mean?  A single topological sort of the whole graph will still satisfy the dependencies of any subset of that graph.

Answer (score 1):

An optimal solution might be constructing a new graph of only the nodes selected by the user, with dependencies assigned appropriately. For example, if A-->B-->C, user picks A and C, your constructed graph is A-->C. Then do a standard topological sort.